# How can I find the direction a sprite is moving?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to get the direction a sprite is moving (up, down, left, right). My current approach is to get the x and y coordinates of the target and the sprite (the sprite is the thing that I'm trying to get the direction of), and then have booleans be true/false based on the the values of the x/y coordinates (if they are greater than, less than, etc.). I'm not trying to rotate the sprite or change anything about how it's drawn, just find the direction that it's moving in. This is what I'm currently trying (this is more of a general idea of what I'm doing, and is pretty rough):

```
if (Target.Position.X < Position.X && Target.Position.Y < Position.Y - 500)
{
    IsFacingUp = false;
    IsFacingDown = false;
    IsFacingLeft = true;
    IsFacingRight = false;
}
else if (Target.Position.X < Position.X && Target.Position.Y > Position.Y + 500)
{
    IsFacingUp = false;
    IsFacingDown = false;
    IsFacingLeft = true;
    IsFacingRight = false;
}
else if (Target.Position.X > Position.X && Target.Position.Y < Position.Y - 500)
{
    IsFacingUp = false;
    IsFacingDown = false;
    IsFacingLeft = false;
    IsFacingRight = true;
}
else if (Target.Position.X > Position.X && Target.Position.Y > Position.Y + 500)
{
    IsFacingUp = false;
    IsFacingDown = false;
    IsFacingLeft = false;
    IsFacingRight = true;
}
else if (Target.Position.Y <= Position.Y - 500)
{
    IsFacingUp = true;
    IsFacingDown = false;
    IsFacingLeft = false;
    IsFacingRight = false;
}
else if (Target.Position.Y >= Position.Y + 500)
{
    IsFacingUp = false;
    IsFacingDown = true;
    IsFacingLeft = false;
    IsFacingRight = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myself, I'd attack it a little something like this:

```
public enum Direction {
    Down,
    Left,    
    None,
    Right,
    Up
}

public static DirectionFromTo(Vector2 from, Vector2 to) {
    Vector2 offset = to - from;
    Vector2 absolute = new Vector2(Abs(offset.x), Abs(offset.y));

    // In your code, it looks like you have a fudge factor to ignore
    // up to a +-500 change in height. You can add that like so...
    float verticalFudge = 500f;

    if (absolute.x > absolute.y - verticalFudge) {
        return offset.x > 0 ? Direction.Right : Direction.Left;
    } 

    if (absolute.y > 0) {
        return offset.y > 0 ? Direction.Down : Direction.Up;
    }

    return Direction.None;
}
```

You can call this with your previous and current positions to get a direction of travel since last frame, or with your current and target positions to get a direction of travel to move in next.

Save the direction you were moving last frame, so you can leave it unchanged in case you have no movement and get `Direction.None` back from this method. That way you'll simply keep your old facing direction instead of flickering or other bugs.

Here's how it might look in place of your current code:

```
var newFacingDirection = DirectionFromTo(Position, Target.Position);

if (newFacingDirection != Direction.None)
   facingDirection = newFacingDirection;
```